freeradius and rml-rest module Configuration errors
I want to use a REST-API to handle authentication (or just fetch users) for my freeradius authentication server.
When I try to start the server I get an error:
/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/rest[17]: Too many closing braces Errors reading or parsing /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf
My /etc/freeradius/mods-available/rest (linked to mods-enabled) looks like this:
rest {
    uri = "<myIPNotTheIssueHere"
    method = "post"

    body = json
    data = "{\"username\": \"%{User-Name}\", \"password\": \"%{User-Password}\"}"

    return_codes {
        ok = 200
        fail = 401
        reject = 403
    }

    headers = {
        Content-Type = "application/json"
    }
}

If I try to remove the headers block, then the startup works but my REST-API isn't called when I try a connection.
My freeradius server runs on a docker container (same for my REST-API).
I am able to make calls on my API directly but not from radius.
